# RowSelected edit TextField in TableCell

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, tableview

I've got a TableView with custom cells, in the cells there is a label and a textfield. I want to focus the textfield when the row is selected.

Anyone knows how to fix this in this code:

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    //EDIT TEXTFIELD FROM SELECTED ROW
}
```

My textfield is indeed in a custom cell class.
I tried this:

```
CustomCell cell = tableView.CellAt (indexPath) as CustomCell;
cell.textField.BecomeFirstResponder();
```

But the textField is never found.

This is my CustomCell class:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace Forms.iOS
{
public class CustomCell : UITableViewCell
{

    UITextField textField;
    UILabel label;

    public CustomCell (NSString cellId) : base (UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, cellId)
    {
        textField = new UITextField ();
        label = new UILabel ();
        ContentView.Add (label);
        ContentView.Add (textField);
    }

    public void UpdateCell (string textFieldValue, string labelValue)
    {
        DetailTextLabel.Text = "Dit is echt nutteloze tekst maar geen idee waarvoor ik dit hier nu neer zet maar zodat het in ieder geval te veel is.";
        textField.Placeholder = textFieldValue;
        TextLabel.Text = labelValue;
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews ()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews ();

        DetailTextLabel.Hidden = true;
        RectangleF detailFrame = DetailTextLabel.Frame;
        textField.Frame = detailFrame;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: For the benefit of anyone looking at this. UITextField textField; needs to be public to access it outside the class (or have a getter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you would need to make the text field the first responder when selecting the row.

```
yourUITextField.BecomeFirstResponder();
```

If your UITextField is a member of some form of custom cell class you could try grab the cell at that location using CellAt, casting it to the custom class and accessing it that way.

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    CustomUITableViewCellClass customCell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath) as CustomUITableViewCellClass;

    if (customCell !=null)
    {
        customCell.yourUITextField.BecomeFirstResponder();
    }
    else
    {
        // Cell at indexPath cannot be cast to CustomUITableViewCellClass
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I also found that but my UITextField is in a different class and I don't how I can get it in my RowSelected method.

Comment: What class is your UITextField in? If you've got a custom class for the cell and the UITextField is a member of that you could try getting the cell at that indexPath and casting it to your custom class to access the member.

CustomUITableViewCellClass cell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath) as CustomUITableViewCellClass;

I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I can't comment on your post as I don't have 50 points yet, but I wouldn't have thought what you've added would compile? You need to specify UITextField textField; UILabel label; as public or create get/set to access them.

Comment: Thanks! I set them as public and now it works great!